# bash: ‘export: command not found

Tags: bash

There is a mistake every time a new terminal is opened,

error: "bash: ‘export: command not found"

I only copy export all_proxy="" and export ALL_PROXY="" to terminal,then when I open a new terminal,in the picture of the situation will be appear.

This is picture:

[image]

I input the command:

```
grep export ~/.bashrc
```

ouput:

[image]

I input the command:

```
env SHELLOPTS=xtrace \
    BASH_XTRACEFD=7 \
    PS4='[${BASH_SOURCE:-$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING}:$LINENO]> ' \
    7> >(grep ‘) bash -l
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the command that gave the error as well as the error itself. It looks like you have a character in front of the command.

Comment: @bu5hman I only copy export all_proxy="" and export ALL_PROXY="" to terminal,then when I open a new terminal,in the picture of the situation will be appear.

Comment: Do other bash commands work? Did you do anything to $PATH in this or the previous terminal session? Or edit your bash profile?

Comment: leading single quote before export  in .bashrc .bash_profile ?

Comment: @bu5hman I don't do anything in $PATH,first occur I reinstall kali linux,the second is still the case.The second I only copy export all_proxy="" and export ALL_PROXY="" to terminal,then when I open a new terminal,in the picture of the situation will be appear.

Comment: @Archemar I don't do anything in .bashrc .bash_profile.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Check ~/.bashrc for a quoted instance of `export`

Comment: @bu5hman OK.I do it.

Comment: Your latest edit shows the culprit. Now the question is: how did those two bogus lines end up there? Did you add them yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have edited your .bashrc file.

I can replicate this error exactly if I put

```
'‘export'
```

as the last line in my .bashrc

To check it just execute

```
grep export ~/.bashrc
```

If `grep` gives an output like the above then edit it out of your ~/.bashrc file.

Edit: From your last post edit you can see that you have 2 lines starting 'export delete them both from ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: Here `\`` is a backtick. The OP had a `‘` character instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Agreed the command is syntactically wrong. The bash error however seems due to the lines in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the command is syntactically correct but just happens to try to invoke a command (`‘export`) which cannot be found.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Agreed. Syntactically correct if you are invoking a new command called `‘export`, but incorrect if you are trying to call `export`. We used to call them typo's. A real devil to get them out of the papyrus.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've copy-pasted that command as-is, it's complaining about the `‘export` command being not found where that `‘` is the U+2018 *left single quotation mark* non-ASCII character (not to be confused with the ASCII `'` apostrophe/single-quote (U+0027) or ASCII `` ` `` backtick/grave accent (U+0060) character).

Since that character is not special in any way to `bash`, a command line like:

```
‘export foo=bar’
```

(where `’` is U+2019, the right single quotation mark)

Is interpreted as running the `‘export` command with `foo=bar’` as argument. Had you written:

```
'export foo=bar'
```

instead, that is with those U+2018 and U+2019 replaced with ASCII apostrophe, a character that is special to `bash` as it's a quoting operator, that would have been treated as running the `export foo=bar` command with no argument. There is no such command. That is not what you want either.

You want

```
export foo=bar
```

or

```
'export' 'foo=bar'
```

That is to run the `export` command with a `foo=bar` argument.

Here, you'll need to remove that U+2018 character (and possibly the corresponding U+2019 character if any) wherever you've inserted it in your `~/.bashrc` or elsewhere. Wherever you copy-pasted that code from, those characters were not intended to be copied.

To find where that bogus command has been introduced if not in `~/.bashrc` (though your latest edit shows it is in your `~/.bashrc` indeed), you could try running:

```
env SHELLOPTS=xtrace \
    BASH_XTRACEFD=7 \
    PS4='[${BASH_SOURCE:-$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING}:$LINENO]> ' \
    7> >(grep ‘) bash -l
```

(the `$PS4` would be ignored by shells running as `root` with bash-4.4 or newer however, which seems to be your case, which is why you see `++` instead of the file name and line number).

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: @MichaelSmith You have to edit `~/.bashrc`, but before that, have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626

Comment: @MichaelSmith, what I said in the answer. You may also want [to get some tutorials or start with an easier unix-like system before using a system intended for professionals](/q/399626)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I copy-pasted the code in answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304988/kali-linux-pip-install-paramiko-get-valueerror

Comment: @MichaelSmith The OP is using Kali but the error is not really related to the distro. Would have happened with Ubuntu too..... don't copy paste

Comment: @bu5hman, true which is why I still gave a comprehensive answer, even if the best advise that can be given specifically to the OP here is not to use Kali until he gets some experience with Linux.

Comment: @bu5hman  I know.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I'm new to kali linux.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Whichever distro you end up using, learn the bash commands and syntax before going much further. The `man` pages can be a bit difficult to start with but there are plenty of good tutorials online and a classic reference book (if you remember books) is the linux bible. Get some practice in.

Comment: @bu5hman OK.I will do that.Thank you.